# FileProvider and system application

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

1. I got a system application with system uid.
2. if it is not build with system uid, fileprovider works well
3. if add system uid & push it into system folder, when i open pdf file using 3rd party, I got a error message from that app " file doesnt exist or cannot open..."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `when i open pdf file using 3rd party` Well show your code with exact path. `push it into system folder,` Please tell exact full path of system folder. You think FileProvider can serve from a system folder? How does your paths.xml look like?  And you try again?